# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "..." violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

Ruby on rails

Following is working on development mySQL

But raise error on Production PG (deploy to Heroku, postgreSQL) and only for some records!

What I have:

- **Car sizes** (S, M, L), for example
- **Car grades** (New, Normal, Old), for example
- **Sizes** and **Grades** make diff **Car Groups** (use has many through), 18 groups in this example.
- Then **Car** belongs to diff **Groups**

When I try to fire command below it works fine 6 times

```
Car.create(reg_no: "001", group_id: 1)
Car.create(reg_no: "002", group_id: 2)
...
```

But

```
Car.create(reg_no: "007", group_id: 7)
```

and others end up with:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "cars" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_fa6b5abc5a"
DETAIL:  Key (group_id)=(7) is not present in table "sizes".
```

So all group_id after 6 are not accepted. I do not understand what makes them different.

Group_id 7 is consist of Size: M and Grade: New, both are present in corresponding tables.

```
irb(main):001:0>Group.find(7)
D, [2018-06-07T14:34:34.802158 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Group id: 7, size_id: 3, grade_id: 1, created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
irb(main):002:0> Size.find(3)
D, [2018-06-07T14:35:59.133721 #4] DEBUG -- :   Size Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Size id: 3, name: "M", created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
irb(main):004:0> Grade.find(1)
D, [2018-06-07T14:36:30.558192 #4] DEBUG -- :   Grade Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Grade id: 1, name: "New", created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
```

Same set of requests for Group 6 that do not raise error

```
irb(main):005:0> Group.find(6)
D, [2018-06-07T15:00:27.431814 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Group id: 6, size_id: 2, grade_id: 3, created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
irb(main):006:0> Size.find(2)
D, [2018-06-07T15:00:40.946858 #4] DEBUG -- :   Size Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes" WHERE "sizes"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Size id: 2, name: "SM", created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
irb(main):007:0> Grade.find(3)
D, [2018-06-07T15:00:49.220472 #4] DEBUG -- :   Grade Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Grade id: 3, name: "Old", created_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26", updated_at: "2018-06-06 18:07:26">
```

MODELS

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  validates :reg_no, presence: true, length: { maximum: 6 },
                     uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :size
  belongs_to :grade
  has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
  validates :size_id, presence: true
  validates :grade_id, presence: true
end

class Size < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grades, through: :groups
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end

class Grade < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sizes, through: :groups
end
```

SCHEMA

```
create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "reg_no"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_cars_on_group_id"
    t.index ["reg_no"], name: "index_cars_on_reg_no", unique: true
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "size_id"
    t.integer "grade_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["grade_id"], name: "index_groups_on_grade_id"
    t.index ["size_id", "grade_id"], name: "index_groups_on_size_id_and_grade_id", unique: true
    t.index ["size_id"], name: "index_groups_on_size_id"
  end

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "grades", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

This is more trace details from server log with last successful creation and first that raise error:

```
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.464588 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.466149 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."size_id" = $1 AND "groups"."grade_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["size_id", 2], ["grade_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.467749 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.469748 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.472005 #4] DEBUG -- :   Car Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "cars" WHERE LOWER("cars"."reg_no") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["reg_no", "ขก685"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.474472 #4] DEBUG -- :   Car Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "cars" ("reg_no", "group_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["reg_no", "ขก685"], ["group_id", 4], ["created_at", "2018-06-07 15:21:00.472251"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-07 15:21:00.472251"]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.476690 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.8ms)  COMMIT

D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.478864 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."size_id" = $1 AND "groups"."grade_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["size_id", 3], ["grade_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.480511 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.482638 #4] DEBUG -- :   Group Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.485111 #4] DEBUG -- :   Car Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "cars" WHERE LOWER("cars"."reg_no") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["reg_no", "ขก681"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.488164 #4] DEBUG -- :   Car Create (1.9ms)  INSERT INTO "cars" ("reg_no", "group_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["reg_no", "ขก681"], ["group_id", 7], ["created_at", "2018-06-07 15:21:00.485387"], ["updated_at", "2018-06-07 15:21:00.485387"]]
D, [2018-06-07T15:21:00.489452 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "cars" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_fa6b5abc5a"
DETAIL:  Key (group_id)=(7) is not present in table "sizes".
: INSERT INTO "cars" ("reg_no", "group_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:603:in `async_exec'
...
```

Comment: can you add the output of Group.find(7) to the question?

Comment: I would not recommend developing on MySQL and deploying to Postgres. MySQL is very lax and sloppy in comparison and you will get issues where MySQL will allow ambigous queries that will error out in production. Setting up postgres locally is not very hard.

Comment: @xploshioOn - done, also added find result on corresponding Size and Group

Comment: @max may be you are right, I just learned ROR like this, so started to develop like this too

Comment: Even developing on MySQL and deploying to Postgres is not recommended it doesn't cancel that fact that this is not working on Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to PG in development so it generate same error.

I can not find how to fix current schema. May be it was because during development I created tables and columns, then change names of columns and tables. Even final schema looks fine but may be on some stage foreign key was not changed properly. When I inspected my migration the only suspicion to me was rename_column even this method change corresponding index too.

So I wrote new migrations with all required details what and even it generates schema that is identical to original one listed here but it helped.

Interesting migration methods that was found during search:

```
add_foreign_key
remove_foreign_key
```

But id doesn't help.

New generated schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_06_09_132438) do

  create_table "cars", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "reg_no"
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_cars_on_group_id"
    t.index ["reg_no"], name: "index_cars_on_reg_no", unique: true
  end

  create_table "grades", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "size_id"
    t.integer "grade_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["grade_id"], name: "index_groups_on_grade_id"
    t.index ["size_id", "grade_id"], name: "index_groups_on_size_id_and_grade_id", unique: true
    t.index ["size_id"], name: "index_groups_on_size_id"
  end

  create_table "prices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "season_id"
    t.integer "amount"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_prices_on_group_id"
    t.index ["season_id"], name: "index_prices_on_season_id"
  end

  create_table "seasons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "start_day"
    t.integer "start_month"
    t.integer "end_day"
    t.integer "end_month"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "sizes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", default: "", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.integer "role", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered the same issue.

What you need is to check your schema.rb and look on the button.

you will see the migration you created before with foreign_key you have to update it again and run a migration.